Performance Issues with .NET Forms Application on Edge Browser after latest update
We are currently experiencing very slow or unresponsive behavior with our .NET forms application specifically on the Edge browser. We have tested the same application on Chrome, where it runs without any issues.
The problem appears to have started following the Version 125.0.2535.51 update of the public release version of the Edge browser. Our investigation using developer tools suggests that the issue is related to JavaScript rendering.
Given that many of our clients use Windows machines and therefore Edge, resolving this issue is critical. Could you advise on how we might optimize our application or suggest any other solutions?

Using developer tools to see time-cost for each request both in Edge and Chrome, and analyzing which request/requests spend much more time, we might narrow down the issue at first.

We are experiencing the same issue also with an asp.net forms site. Edge's Performance analyzer says it is spending 500ms chunks of time "Parsing HTML" of a large < select > tag. 2-300 rows per 500ms chunk. No other browser is showing this issue, nor are Edge Canary/Beta on 127/126. Only Edge stable v125. All others parse all 10k < options > no issue, meanwhile Edge takes 20x longer and is using 5-10x the RAM chrome does to load the same page.
Edit: It's a confirmed issue with Chromium, update Chrome or use a beta build of edge as a current workaround.  https://issues.chromium.org/issues/341095522?pli=1

It looks like a known issue with Edge version 125: Edge tab will hang or crash on select drop down with large number of options.
Please check if the document contains a select drop down with a large number of options and also test in Edge Beta 126: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/download/insider?form=MA13FJ. The issue is fixed in Edge 126 and fix will be available in next sub version of 125.
